# How do I control the upload/download bandwidth per user?

Tags: bandwidth

How to control bandwidth upload and download per user or each ip/mac?
i tried squid3.0stable25 with delay_pools but its not work. is it really possible to control bandwidth for each host by squid? my isp have 400 more host but they are using open bw. i want to limit there upload and download how to do it? i also try htb but setup failed or not working and didn't get perfect example. please help!!

Comment: Also see [Is there an easy way to limit user bandwidth usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-limit-user-bandwidth-usage)

Answer (score 3):

[Mastershaper](https://github.com/Mithrilhall/MasterShaper) can do this. From their website:

MasterShaper is a network traffic shaper which provides a Web Interface for Quality of Servcie (QoS) functions of newer Linux 2.4- & 2.6-Kernel-Series.

It targets to let users learn and use the traffic shaping mechanism. This should be possible for everyone who has no deeper knowledge of Linux and the difficult syntax of the tc commands from the iproute2 package.

It provides a Web Interface which lets you define bandwidth pipes and filters (based on IP, MAC, ports, protocols, ipp2p, layer7-filter, ...). It also draws some graphs about the current bandwidth usage and distribution. There is no more need for any shell access or privileged users.

Image of the 'ruleset overview':

[image]

Comment: Does this handle traffic on a per-user basis? Their documentation PDF has gone walkies so it's hard to verify but the screenshot above suggest this is per-protocol.

Comment: The website linked in this answer seems to now redirect to some other sketchy site, so I've replaced it with a link to what appears to be the GitHub repo for MasterShaper. Feel free to edit as needed if there's a better link.

Comment: @V2Blast cool No problem here with that